# Unwind Segue with Multiple Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, segue

I have been working on a project that is starting to get rather large to retain in one storyboard. I have successfully used segues and unwind segues as I need to tranfer information between views.  When I split the project into more storyboards the unwind segues do not always work.  I have researched this site and have also done some investigative work in a test area.

In my test area if I am starting with a view controller in the main storyboard segue to a controller in a new storyboard I can unwind with no problem. If I start from a controller in a new storyboard, call it A.storyboard and segue to a controller in storyboard B, I cannot unwind. It is not finding the unwind action. I assume it is looking at view controllers in main.storyboard and not finding the action. There is something I am missing in working with multiple storyboards. Is there a way to specify the storyboard to go back to ?

Before I wrote this question I had looked at 'Can an Unwind Segue work between two storyboards'. Both the answers work if I want to go back to Main.Storyboard. This was already working for me.  So if I have main going to second storyboard I can get back to main.This works for any number of storyboards However if I have third storyboard and want to go to fourth storyboard I cannot get back to third storyboard. I have used both of the ways suggested in the 2duplicate" question. I see the IB Action to select but it just doesn't work. Is it something I am doing wrong in setting up new storyboards ?

Comment: I don't have an answer but I'm curious.  How do you even connect a segue to a controller that's in a different storyboard?

Comment: Add Storyboard Reference and then connect to that as if it were a view controller. Works really well.

Comment: No I did look at that in my research and it does not answer the question regarding unwinding to a storyboard other than the main storyboard. Or if it does I didn't understand it !

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The problem exists even with the solution mentioned in the other SO question.